# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I'm facing problem while trying new installation of magento on server. When I extract the zip file and access by browser then that bellow error comes:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 64314 bytes) in
>   C:\HostingSpaces\mygarden\mygarden.pk\wwwroot\app\Mage.php on line 907

**I changed memory limit** to `256` in `.htaccess`
and also changed memory limit in `php.ini` file.

but issue never resolved, please reply me with good solution

thanks

Comment: [See here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30445/adding-a-product-in-magento-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-41943040-bytes) and [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38415/php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-on-indexer-php-action)

Answer (score 1):

Bumping your memory limit to 512M should help with your situation.  Try that and see if you still have issues.

Are you on shared hosting?  Does your provider allow you to tweak your settings?

In PHP.ini:

> memory_limit 512M

In .htaccess:

> php_value memory_limit 512M

Comment: in which file? in php.ini file or .htaccess file?

Comment: i change memory limit 256 to 512 in php.ini file but still got same error :-(

Comment: 536870912 bytes exhausted ...