# Fatal error: Allowed memory size

Tags: fatal-error

I have a strange behaviour on this Magento website: http://us.karinherzog.com
It happens sometimes for some customers and finally also to me today.

The Magento admin is fully accessible but the frontend is not. I have a "Fatal error: Allowed memory size" error message. 
The error message is always different each time I refresh the page. Here are some examples:

- Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /var/www/karin-herzog-usa/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Collection/Abstract.php on line 119
- Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /var/www/karin-herzog-usa/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Item/Option/Collection.php on line 71
- Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 512 bytes) in /var/www/karin-herzog-usa/magento/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 270
- Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /var/www/karin-herzog-usa/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 1016
- ...

Here is what I have noticed:

- On the browser I usually used the error is not display. The website works great. I have used this browser these last days to go on this website.
- On the others browsers I have on my computer, it doesn't work, I have the error message. It's the first time I open the website on these browser since a few weeks.
- If I clear the cache of one of this browser, the error message disappear and the website works again.

Does one you know what could be the problem? Why not everyone has this error and why if I clear the cache of the browser the error goes away?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**Additional notes** : As I have mentioned above, the website was working on my usual browser. Today after creating a new cart price rule in the admin, the same problem appear in this browser. To fix the problem I had to clear the cache and cookies on this browser. After that I have tried to edit this cart rule and the problem came back again... I hope this information will help someone discover what the problem is.

Comment: Try deleting files from the [Magento Directory]/var/cache

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the same problem can you find here: [Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64314 bytes) in](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50111/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-536870912-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate)

You need to set *memory_limit*.

Comment: Thank you for this link but it doesn't help. It is something I already tried and the memory limit is already at 512Mb.